# Advanced verticalization with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm stuck on a Flexbox use case:

I have a horizontal layout for 2 grids with a central (fixed-width ) commands column which allows user to get left grid elements in the right one. See the following scheme:

[image: Large layout]

On a smaller screen, I would like to horizontalize those buttons and not to waste vertical space. See the following scheme:

[image]

Anyone would have an idea on how to manage this?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) with either the `column` or `row` [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction), based on the screen width. Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to switch between both views:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.box div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
 .box {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .box :nth-child(1),
  .box :nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .box :nth-child(2) {
    flex: 0 1 100px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>1</div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="button">A</button>
    <button type="button">B</button>
    <button type="button">C</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That @media and min-width trick is awesome ! Thank you